# Getting Id of the newly created object with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

My repository is being exposed through `UnitOfWork` and `Add` method have only following code:

```
public void Add(Employee emp)
{
    context.add(emp);
}
```

Then, from UnitOfWork, i am calling the Add() method with this code:

```
this.UnitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Create(emp);
this.UnitOfWork.Commit(); // This calls SaveChanges() EF method
```

Now the issue is how can i obtain the `Id` of newly created object here?

Answer (score 1):

Normally if your `Id` is  Identity, when you save changes the `Id` will be automatically filled.

```
context.Employees.Add(emp);
context.SaveChanges();
var newId=emp.Id; //The Id is filled after save changes
```

A second variant could be using the [`GetDatabaseValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696244(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
context.Entry(emp).GetDatabaseValues();
var id = emp.Id;
```

Comment: So calling repository through UOW will still give me Id as it's an identity column

Comment: It should have the new value, but anyway check the `Id` of you `emp` instances after call the `Commit` method, if it doesn't have the new `Id` value, then use the second variant.

Answer (score 0):

After `SaveChanges` the employee entity wil have the new id assigned. Find a way to return it to higher level methods.